# Catel: multiple ViewModels with one View. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, catel

I got a generic base-class for ViewModel of my user-control:

```
public class SuggestModule<TEntity> : ViewModelBase 
        where TEntity : class, ISuggestable, new()
    {
        public SuggestModule(ISomeService someService)
        {
            // Some logic
        }

        // Some private fields, public properties, commands, etc...
    }
}
```

Whitch has many inheritable classes. That is two of them, for example:

```
public class CitizenshipSuggestViewModel : SuggestModule<Citizenship>
{
    public CitizenshipSuggestViewModel(ISomeService someService) 
        : base(someService) { }       
}

public class PlaceOfBirthSuggestViewModel : SuggestModule<PlaceOfBirth>
{
    public PlaceOfBirthSuggestViewModel(ISomeService someService) 
        : base(someService) { }       
}
```

That is view implementation:

```
<catel:UserControl
    x:Class="WPF.PRC.PBF.Views.UserControls.SuggestUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:pbf="clr-namespace:WPF.PRC.PBF">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" />
        // Other elements, behaviors, other extensive logic...
    </Grid>

</catel:UserControl>
```

Now, in MainWindow creating two ContentControls:

```
<catel:Window
    x:Class="WPF.PRC.PBF.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CitizenshipSuggestViewModel, Converter={catel:ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding PlaceOfBirthSuggestViewModel, Converter={catel:ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />

    </Grid>

</catel:Window>
```

Due to violation of the Naming Convention, manually resolving a ViewModel in App.xaml.cs:

```
    var viewModelLocator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewModelLocator>();
    viewModelLocator.Register(typeof(SuggestUserControl), typeof(CitizenshipSuggestViewModel));
    viewModelLocator.Register(typeof(SuggestUserControl), typeof(PlaceOfBirthSuggestViewModel));

    var viewLocator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewLocator>();
    viewLocator.Register(typeof(CitizenshipSuggestViewModel), typeof(SuggestUserControl));
    viewLocator.Register(typeof(PlaceOfBirthSuggestViewModel), typeof(SuggestUserControl));
```

But now I have two views with identical ViewModels.
How can I solve this problem without creation of identical Views with repetition of the code in each of them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [auto-fac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633722/how-do-i-use-dtos-with-ef-autofac-and-a-generic-data-repository/21634064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Repeat yourself so if one needs customization in the future, you can customize just 1 without much overhead. The downside is that if you need to check the generic behavior, you'll need to change them all.
2. Create an enum representing the state that a VM is representing. In that case, you can simply creat a *single* vm that catches all of the cases that you need to handle. You can solve this using a dependency property on the view and by using `ViewToViewModelMapping` to automatically map this to the vm. This comes closest to achieving code-reusage as you wish to achieve with your view. It does go a bit against "separation of concerns", but since it represents the *same sort of data* I believe it's still a good approach.

For 2, you need to do the following:

1 Create an enum `SuggestEntityType` with `PlaceOfBirth`, `Citizenship`, etc

2 Create a property on the vm (this example code is assuming you are using Catel.Fody):

```
public SuggestedEntityType EntityType { get; set; }
```

3 Create a dependency property on the view:

```
[ViewToViewModel(MappingType = ViewToViewModelMappingType.ViewToViewModel)]
public SuggestedEntityType EntityType
{
    get { return (SuggestedEntityType) GetValue(EntityTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EntityTypeProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty EntityTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EntityType", typeof (SuggestedEntityType),
    typeof (MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

4 You can now use the user control like this:

```
<controls:MyView EntityType="Citizenship" />
```

For more info, see http://docs.catelproject.com/vnext/catel-mvvm/view-models/mapping-properties-from-view-to-view-model/

Comment: Thank you, Geert!

I'm a beginner programmer, so I apologize for the many clarifying questions.
How correctly I understand you? I need to create enum something like "SuggestEntityTypes": CitizenshipSuggesting, PlaceOfBirthSuggesting.
Than in code-behind of my SuggestUserControl create dependency property SuggestEntityType.
Now, in MainWindow.xaml add this: <userControls:SuggestUserControl SuggestEntityType="CitizenshipSuggesting" />
And... Where should I use ViewToViewModelMapping? Is there any obvious example?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a dependencyProperty in your UserControl codebehind, for example

```
   #region Properties       

    public string Test
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty TestProperty =
       System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(string), typeof(YourUserControl), new System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });


    #endregion Dependency Properties
```

Then in your xaml you can bind this property as :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type catel:UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
```

Then in your MainWindow you can write:

```
  <views:YourUserControlName Test="{Binding SomeTextPropertyFromMainWindowVM}"/>
```

So you will be able to bind from the property SomeTextPropertyFromMainWindowVM in your windowVM to some property in your userControl.

If you have in your main window several viewModels, you can write like:

```
<views:YourUserControlName Test="{Binding SomeViewModel.SomeTextProperty}"/>
<views:YourUserControlName Test="{Binding SomeOtherViewModel.SomeTextProperty}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need a solution, whitch stay in Catel framework design